# Confidence interval of Poisson distributed MLE using chi squared

Tags: confidence-interval, maximum-likelihood, poisson-regression, chi-squared-distribution

There is a variable distributed as $X$~Poisson$(X_0 e^{-\lambda t})$. The value of $\lambda$ was estimated through maximum likelihood by fitting to the data $t=0,1,2,3,4$ and $X=[5000,3000,100,10,1]$.
Now I want to find the confidence interval around this estimated $\lambda$.

In  [here](https://biol607.github.io/lab/07_likelihood.html), the CI is taken as "CI of each parameter is 1.92 away from the Maximum Log-Likelihood"
I guess 1.92 comes from a Chi Squared distribution as in [section 2.3 page 740](https://sci-hub.tw/10.1088/0031-9155/53/3/014) it is mentioned that "The 95% lower and upper confidence bounds were determined as parameter values that reduce the optimal likelihood by $χ^2 (0.05,1)/2 = 1.92.  $"

So, according to this is the confidence interval = $(\lambda-1.92,\lambda+1.92)$, where this $\lambda $ was found from the maximum likelihood estimation?

However, I don't understand how this Chi Squared distribution came into the confidence interval of a Poisson distribution?  Can someone please let me know on what this is based on?
How does it have 1 degrees of freedom?